# JAVASCRIPT CLASS instance default method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently went for an interview and got a question on JAVASCRIPT which I could not answer, but i would really like to know the answer, but I do not know how to phrase it in google.

The question is:

```
var a = new A();
a(); // return 1
a(); // return 2

var b = new A();
b(); //return 1;
b(); //return 2;
```

Implement A

How can I solve this using javascript. I got this so far

```
class A {
  constructor(){
    this.num = 1;
  }
  function(){
    console.log(this.num--);
  }
}
```

Comment: if invoking `a()` increases from 1 to 2, why are you decrementing?

Comment: Does it have to be a class…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), A class constructor or a function can return a value other than `this`. According to MDN:

> The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of
>   the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>   explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>   instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>   choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>   process.)

So a possible answer to this question is to return a function from the constructor:

```js
class A {
  constructor(){
    this.num = 1;
    
    return this.func.bind(this); // bind the function to `this`
  }
  
  func() {
    console.log(this.num++);
  }
}

var a = new A();
a(); // return 1
a(); // return 2

var b = new A();
b(); //return 1;
b(); //return 2;
```

**Possible uses:**

After answering this question, I've started to think about the legitimate uses of the return value.

1. Singleton

```js
class Singleton {
  constructor() {
    if(Singleton.instance) {
      return Singleton.instance;
    }
    
    Singleton.instance = this;
    
    return this;
  }
}

console.log(new Singleton() === new Singleton()); // true
```

2. Encapsulated module using the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) with a class

```js
class Module {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    
    return {
      increment: this.increment.bind(this),
      decrement: this.decrement.bind(this),
      getValue: this.getValue.bind(this),
    };
  }
  
  increment() {
    this.value++;
  }
  
  decrement() {
    this.value--;
  }
  
  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

const module = new Module(5);

module.increment();
module.increment();
module.decrement();

console.log(module.value); // undefined
console.log(module.getValue()); // 6
```

Comment: All previous comments were wiped for some reason. It should be noticed that fundamental problem with returning `this.func.bind(this)` is that it it doesn't expose `A` instance (`this`) and `num` state. Considering that it's 'default' method, there's no way to call non-default methods. So the whole class doesn't make sense and exists just to satisfy the requirement to have ES6 class (which is XY problem because interview question was incorrectly interpreted by the OP).

Comment: The class continues to live in the closure, and the methods are the interface to it. It turns out, that there are some uses for that, although it still looks quirky. See the "Possible uses" at the end of the question.

Comment: I'd call it 'only' method, not 'default' then, but that's the problem with original question. Yes, possible uses look more reasonable (although at this point a class is usually considered antipattern, because it's a job for plain objects and functions).

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear whether using a `class` is required; here's a solution using a simple closure and basically ignoring the `new` keyword:

```js
function A() {
    var i = 1;
    
    return function () {
        console.log(i++);
    }
}

var a = new A();
a();
a();

var b = new A();
b();
b();
```

Comment: This has the possibly important advantage of keeping the counter variable private.

Comment: this seems neater, but I didnt know you can use new on a function

Answer (score 3):

This is XY problem. There is no requirement to use ES6 class in interview question. It is misused here because it cannot provide any reasonable class design (it makes no sense from OOP point of view and requires unreasonable prototype hacking from JS point of view).

There is no such thing as 'default' method, this isn't how OOP works. `new` creates an instance of a class, and in order to receive a function as an instance, a class should be a child of `Function`, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432292/3731501) is technically correct, although impractical.

The answers don't really explain that, but the proper answer to this interview question is:

*New function should be returned from constructor function.*

```
function A(num = 0) {
  return () => ++num;
}

var a = new A();
a(); // return 1
a(); // return 2
```

*It is workable, but there is no reason to use this function as a constructor. It's expected that class instance is used to store **and** expose `num` state, and there is no good way to use `this` as class instance in this capacity because prototypal inheritance between constructor and returned function weren't established. `new` provides additional overhead without any purpose. The solution is purely functional, and the use of `new` is the mistake, so it should be omitted.*

```
var a = A();
a(); // return 1
a(); // return 2
```

And there is a good chance that the one who asks the question will be frustrated by the answer; it's unlikely that this was a catch for A+ answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
class A {
  constructor () {
    this.num = 1
    return () => {
      console.log(this.num++)
    }
  }
}
```